# Error when trying to convert a column with string in Python Pandas to Float

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column named 'market_cap_(in_us_$)' which values are like:

```
$5.41 
$18,160.50 
$9,038.20 
$8,614.30 
$368.50 
$2,603.80 
$6,701.50 
$8,942.40
```

My final goal is to be able to filter based on specific numeric values (for example, > 2000.00).

By reading other questions in this site, I followed the instructions as:

```
cleaned_data['market_cap_(in_us_$)'].replace( '$', '', regex = True ).astype(float)
```

However, I receiving the following error

```
TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'
```

If I remove the "regex = True" from the replace arguments, I get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: $5.41
```

So, what should I do?

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you running?  (`print pd.__version__`)

Comment: I had the 0.11.0, after your suggestion I updated it to the 0.14.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right regular expression to use is given here, as you want to remove the `$` and `,`:

```
In [7]:

df['market_cap_(in_us_$)'].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
Out[7]:
0        5.41
1    18160.50
2     9038.20
3     8614.30
4      368.50
5     2603.80
6     6701.50
7     8942.40
Name: market_cap_(in_us_$), dtype: float64
```

But since you got that `keyword argument 'regex'` error, you must be using a very old version, and should update.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `$` is a special character in regular expression which means the start of the string, so replacing just the start of the string ends up not replacing anything!

You have to use `str.replace` on the Series (with the literal $ and ,):

```
In [11]: s.replace('\$|,', '', regex=True)
Out[11]:
0        5.41
1    18160.50
2     9038.20
3     8614.30
4      368.50
5     2603.80
6     6701.50
7     8942.40
dtype: object

In [12]: s.replace('\$|,', '', regex=True).astype('float64')
Out[12]:
0        5.41
1    18160.50
2     9038.20
3     8614.30
4      368.50
5     2603.80
6     6701.50
7     8942.40
dtype: float64
```

It may be you want to use whole cents rather than float dollars (removing the literal .):

```
In [13]: s.replace('\$|,|\.', '', regex=True).astype('int64')
Out[13]:
0        541
1    1816050
2     903820
3     861430
4      36850
5     260380
6     670150
7     894240
dtype: int64
```